# MYSQL: Select sum values from one column into multiple columns grouped by values selected from second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

Table 'Earning':

```
id | amount | date       | currency_id
-----------------------------
0  | 100000 | 01-01-2015 | 0
1  | 200000 | 01-01-2015 | 1
2  | 300000 | 01-01-2015 | 0
3  | 400000 | 02-01-2015 | 1
4  | 500000 | 02-01-2015 | 1
```

Table 'Currencies':

```
id | Code
---------
0  | USD
1  | EUR
```

So we have possibility to add new currency at any time.

Is it possible to select from both tables to get following result?

```
date       | Earned_USD | Earned_EUR
-------------------------------------
01-01-2015 | 400000     | 200000
02-01-2015 | 0          | 900000
```

Thank you a lot!

Comment: If you want a separate column for each currency, then google "mysql dynamic pivot".

Comment: So how many currencies are possible ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: Why? 3-5 for now... But if such select is possible - there's no limit. Is'n it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thanx! Very useful.